# opencv-python basic ORB feature detection gives me error -215 in function cv::drawKeypoints

Tags: python, opencv, orb

this is the basic code from opencv-python documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 18, in <module>
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\features2d\src\draw.cpp:115: error:       (-215) !outImage.empty() in function cv::drawKeypoints
```

i have to mention this error happens in opencv-PYTHON, can you help me out please? struggling really to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the solution
it couldn't find the image

i changed

```
img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)
```

to

```
img = cv2.imread('c:\\python27\\sample.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

and it worked

note that the image i used for the sample image was one of my own grayscale images.

Comment: I have the same problem. Your solution did not solve my issue. Is there any other solution for the same?